# Initialize and Declare Bundle in same line while sending data from one fragment to another

Tags: android, android-fragments

So the problem is not a technical issue, but more of an aesthetic kind.

I am passing data from one fragment to another fragment. So there are 3 fragments in total and the first two are calling the same 3rd fragment, so to identify in the third fragment from which of the first two it was invoked I am using the following code

in the first fragment

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putBoolean("isFirst", true)
Fragment fragment = new ThirdFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
loadFragment(fragment);
```

and in the second fragment as

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putBoolean("isFirst", false)
Fragment fragment = new ThirdFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
loadFragment(fragment);
```

and in the third fragment

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
Boolean isFirst = bundle.getBoolean("isFirst",false);
if(isFirst){
....
} else{
....
}
```

the code works fine but I think there should be a more elegant way of doing it. If not atleast make the whole thing into one line without additional declarations such as Bundle bundle and Fragment fragment

for example something like

```
loadFragment(new ThirdFragment().setArguments(new Bundle().putBoolean("isFirst",true)));
```

I am relatively new to android and java programming so please don't be harsh.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare static method getInstance(Boolean isFirst) in ThirdFragment example

```
public static ThirdFragment getInstance(Boolean isFirst) {
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putBoolean("isFirst", isFirst)
   Fragment fragment = new ThirdFragment();
   fragment.setArguments(bundle);
   return fragment
}
```

In First and SecondFragment call

```
loadFragment(ThirdFragment.getInstance(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create `newIstance()` in `ThirdFragment` like stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

you can also achieve the same by the below code

```
public class Util {

static Fragment getThirdFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Boolean isFirst, @NonNull ClassLoader classLoader, @NonNull String className) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean("isFirst", isFirst);
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.getFragmentFactory().instantiate(classLoader, className);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
    }
}
```

and call it

```
loadFragment(Util.getThirdFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(),true/*is first boolean value*/, ThirdFragment.class.getClassLoader(), ThirdFragment.class.getName()));
```

**Kotlin**

put this code inside `ThirdFragment`

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(param1: Boolean) =
            ThirdFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putBoolean("isFirst", param1)
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `bundleOf("key" to "value")` ex :

```
findNavController(it).navigate(
    R.id.action_sendSmsFragment_to_webViewFragment,
    bundleOf(
    "age" to 25,
    "name" to "Michael",
    "skill" to null
     )
 )
```